# Certificate for some web pages

Tags: ios, macos, certificate

I have a certificate which is required for some web pages.

I can send it via mail / ask the users to download it via my app, but in both cases, I read that it would only effect Apple-provided apps such as Safari or Mail.

I want it to effect also Chrome.
What can I do regarding this?

Edit: 
Asking also for OS X and for iOS

Comment: Well, it started working, but I'll wait before deleting the question to understand why it is working even when it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are typically installed in a 'trusted' directory in the OS like `/etc/ssl/certs` in Linux and are accessible to all applications regardless of their origin. In the Mac environment, certificates are installed using the Keychain and once you are done installing, they will become accessible to Safari, Mail, Chrome etc because they all use the Keychain to figure out which certificates to trust. It really doesn't matter whether it is an Apple-provided app or not.

Comment: Great, but what about this - "Apps can only access keychain items in their own keychain access groups. This means that items in the Apple access group are only available to Apple-provided apps such as Safari or Mail."
Taken from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1745/_index.html

Comment: And I asked for iOS also it it has a different behavior

Comment: Ok, I missed out on the iOS tag. My answer was for Mac OS X. I don't have access to an iOS device, so I may not be able to help you out on this one. Someone with an iOS background may fare better.